# Opening ec2 ports using security groups

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, port

I'm trying to open all ports up to a micro instance that I have set up, but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omnjp.png

Using [paping](http://code.google.com/p/paping/), I find that port 22 is open but 80 (and others that I can see) is closed. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually running services on those ports? Did you open the ports in the server's firewall? All ports but 22 are firewalled by default on Red Hat-derived systems, while Debian-derived systems ship with the firewall off.

Comment: Looks like he's using amazon's AMI (which is debian-based) so no firewall. Probably just nothing listening on the port...

Comment: Aha, I see Ubuntu 13.04 in the screenshot.

Comment: Oh, whoops. He's using ubuntu. And you're right ...it appears to be redhat based (it uses yum too) but the firewall is off by default.

Comment: @NathanC That leaves you with "the service isn't running"...